# .NET Standard equivalent of Thread.CurrentCulture

Tags: .net, localization, .net-core, .net-standard

With the full .NET framework, you can get/set the current thread's culture and UI culture using:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

I'm porting a library to `netstandard1.n` (`n` is to be determined) and discovered the `Thread` class does not define `CurrentCulture` nor `CurrentUICulture`.

Is there an alternative API for this?

Answer (score 10):

Use `CultureInfo`'s static members instead:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

Comment: Hrm, but these are read-only in .NET Framework. Is there a way which doesn't include `#if` preproc directives?